# Default Text missing during facebook share in Iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

In an App developed we are facing problem when sharing some feature of the App in Facebook. The default text that we intend to share does not seem to appear. However there is no issue when there is an image  present to be shared by the Facebook application.

We have implemented the Facebook integration, but things don't give us the desired outcome. Refer to attached image for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because Facebook has deprecated the functionality to pre-fill the caption text programmatically. Below is the reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

I also faced the same problem with one of my app last month and I came to this conclusion.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use FBSDKShareLinkContent with FBSDKSHAREKIT

```
 FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
 content.contentTitle = // HERE YOUR TEXT TITLE
 content.contentDescription = // HERE YOUR TEXT / DESCRIPTION;
 content.imageURL = // YOUR IMAGE URL;
 [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:(UIViewController *)self.delegate
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:self];
```